# can we declare cursor outside procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am not able to declare cursor.
what is significance of cursor in mysql

```
declare c1 cursor for select name from record
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'declare c1 cursor for select name from record' at
>   line 1

Comment: Sometimes you need something procedureal

Comment: If you have a front end it can also do this with an ADODB object and scroll throught Recordsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors are used inside a stored programs to go through a result set (i.e. they are not available outside the stored programs).

Do remember that SQL is set based, so try to think first if the task you are trying to do can be resolved using normal (select/insert/update/delete). Serializing the queries via cursors should be a last solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , You can use MySQL cursors in stored procedures, stored functions, and triggers.

for your reference - [Cursor in - procedure , functions and triggers](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/)

Answer (score 0):

Cursors also work in anonymous blocks in MySQL/MariaDB.

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    DECLARE sName VARCHAR(80);
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM record;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN myCursor;
    my_loop: LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO sName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;

        /* do something with sName */
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE myCursor;
END$$
```